# Passing a parameter with h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameter-passing, commandbutton

I have a a4j:commandButton which is supposed to redirect me to an appropriate "Edit" page based on an Id, which I wanted to pass as a parameter, something like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="/details.jsf?faces-redirect=true" value="details">
    <f:attribute name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem is, it doesn't work. I also tried replacing f:attribute with "f:param name="id" value="#{bean.id}" ", but it also failed. The only thing I got to work is an outputLink:

```
<h:outputLink  value="/details.jsf">
    link
    <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

But I'm not really happy with a link, so is there a way to make the commandButton work?

Oh and I also have a bean which is supposed to get that "id" after the redirect:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    id= resolve("id");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to fire a GET or POST request? UICommand is always POST, but it sounds/looks like you rather want a GET.

Comment: Well I guess GET would be more appropriate in this case, but I would be also ok with a working POST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) about communication in JSF, by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

`f:param` only works with `h:commandLink` and `h:outputLink`.

You can use an input hidden:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="/details.jsf?faces-redirect=true" value="details"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</h:form>
```

And then in your faces-config, I guess is request scoped. If you use the annotations of JSF2, just translate this to the proper annotations.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>mypackage.Bean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>id</property-name>
        <value>#{param.id}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

You need obviously to have getters and setters for that field in the backing bean.

or try to "paint" the link as a button through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Unless my JSF is extremely rusty, the action attribute on a command button or command link is used to specify the outcome string defined in your faces-config-nav file, or it should point to a method on the bean which will return an outcome (or redirect/whatever).

In your case, if you want to redirect to another page... you should define that in your config file, as a navigation link (with `redirect` if necessary). Then in your action button you should have something like

```
<h:commandButton action="showDetails" value="details">
```

...

```
<navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>showDetails</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/details.jsf?faces-redirect=true</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

As an aside, the `<f:atribute>` tag will work, but it will only set the attribute onto the component. So if you got a hold of the command button in your bean, you could be able to get the attribute value by name. To pass a request param, use the hidden field technique like **pakore** mentioned

Comment: Exactly what I thought. The commandButton's 'action' attribute doesn't describe the target url but the outcome. You can then map the outcome to the target path in your navigation config file (or write you own navigation handler).